# Javascript insert a method call inside another external function

Tags: javascript, function, methods, extend

Consider this

```
var obj = {
    process: function run(param) {

        return;
    }
}
```

and

```
runSomething(param);
```

The situation is that the `run` function is built elsewhere in the application and contains some additional processing that need to be done to the `runSomething` response.

is it possible to somehow run `obj.run` and insert the `runSomething` into it, so that `runSomething` can use the param that was passed in as `obj.run("something")`

Producing the same result as

```
var obj = {
    process: function run(param) {

                return runSomething(param);
             }
}
```

Comment: Is this [*Currying*](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html)?

Comment: Do you always refer to the same function by `run`, `runSomething`, and `process`?

Comment: @RobG: No, it rather is function composition.

Comment: for the example yes, they would never change. deolectrix worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
    var obj = {
            process: function run(funct, param) {


                return funct(param);
            }
        }

   obj.process(runSomething, param);
```

Comment: I believe that will do it. Thx!